# What's an attribute? How does it "hold" a value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, attributes, dice

What does it mean for an attribute to hold something, and how is it executed in code?

More specifically, what exactly is an attribute in OOP Python? How can it hold a certain value, for example, "Jack"? Is an attribute similar to a variable? Some questions I'm wondering.

Comment: something like this? ```die(face = "------\n| o o |\n| o o |\n| o o |\n ------", faceValue = 6)```

Comment: When you reach a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful answers and accept the best (even if you have to write it yourself).  This allows Stack Overflow to archive your question.

Answer (score 1):

An attribute of a class or object is *any* of the member items: a method, a variable, etc.  In this case, it's a variable.  From this, I assume that you know what it means to hold a value.

Get rid of the string `face` attribute; this is merely the display rendition of the value.  Store those renditions in a list or dict, and encapsulate that within your display method.  For instance:

```
face_image = {
    1: ' ------\n|     |\n| o |\n|     |\n ------',
    2: ' ------\n| o   |\n|   |\n|   o |\n ------',
    ...
```

... and when you need it ...

```
print(face_image[self.value])
```

Does that get you moving?

Comment: Actually, one more thing - if I need to have the self attribute, how can I execute this?

Comment: (1) That sounds like a separate question.  (2) That depends on what you mean by "the self attribute".  I strongly recommend *against* naming an attribute `self`, because that is the traditional name for the symbiont instance -- you're already using it that way.

Comment: That's in my answer: "... and when you need it ..."

Comment: I'm still not sure what it means for an attribute to hold a certain value or values...

Comment: What do you not understand about a variable holding a value?

Comment: So, for example, "face" can hold the value "' ------\n|     |\n| o |\n|     |\n ------'"? I understand that, but how can I make it so that depending on the "faceValue" I can change the "face" attribute without any dict?

Comment: I don't know how you would do it in any fashion better than using the lookup table (dict).  You've already expressed a willingness to hard-code all six possibilities; what characteristics of the solution do you want that the dict does not provide?

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a class as a blueprint, and an object of that class as the manifestation of that class. In this light, attributes are like the characteristics of objects that can be defined at the class level i.e `class attributes` and at a particular instance of a class i.e `instance attributes`